# Initial segment of $\mathbb{Z}$ not determined by an element

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

So I'm a little confused by the following theorem:

> $X$ is well ordered iff every proper initial segment is determined by an element.

My confusion lies in applying this to $\mathbb{Z}$. It seem's to me that every proper initial segment of $\mathbb{Z}$ is determined by an element in $\mathbb{Z}$, which would imply that $\mathbb{Z}$ is well-ordered which we know is false.

So my question is where have I made a mistake in my reasoning. I feel it must be in saying that every initial segment is determined by an element in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What does "determined by an element" mean? And where did you see this statement?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Presumably the initial segment determined by an element $x\in X$ is $\{y\in X:y<x\}$.

Comment: So if $X$ is well ordered and the proper initial segment detetermined by $x \in X$ is $PISD(x) = \{y \in X: y < x\}$, and if $a$ is the least element of $X$.... then we can claim $PISD(a) = \{y \in X: y < a\}=\emptyset$.  Am I understanding that correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty set is a proper initial segment of $\mathbb{Z}$ but there is no $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\emptyset=\{y\in\mathbb{Z}:y<x\}$, since $\mathbb{Z}$ has no least element.